# How do I divide a dataframe based on the content in the rows of a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get two dataframes out of one. The dataframe has two set of words (neutral and non neutral) so I need to divide it in a dataset that only has neutral words and another that only has non neutral words (mantaining all the rows and columns). These words are in a column called PALABRA.

This is an example of the words in a variable (they are a lot more than these):

```
neutral_words = ('CAR','CLOUD','SUN')
nonneutral_words = ('ACCIDENT','BUG','BURN')
```

The df looks like this:

```
   PRESSEDKEY  PALABRA   COLOR KEYCORR    RT CORRECT
90           v      BURN    red       r   496       N
96           v       SUN    red       r  1307       N
102          v       BUG    red       r     0       N
108          v     CLOUD   blue       a   168       N
114          v   ACCIDENT  green      v    73       Y
```

This way, I need to divide the dataframe in df1 with neutral_words only and df2 with nonneutral_words. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[df['PALABRA'].isin(neutral_words)]
df2 = df.loc[df['PALABRA'].isin(nonneutral_words)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use the `isin` function.

Something like:

```
df1=df[df.Palabra.isin(['ACCIDENT','BUG','BURN'])])
```

or

```
df1=df[df.Palabra.isin(nonneutral_words)
```

Comment: There's no difference compared to my answer and it was posted 2 minutes later. It is normally not a good practice to post a solution if it doesn't expand/impove upon those posted earlier

Comment: I was in the process of writing it. I didn't see yours until I posted mine.

Comment: Sure, this happens a lot (with me as well, of course), but it's best to delete your answer if it doesn't add anything to what's already posted